# What is $x^{\overline{-n}}$?

Tags: combinatorics

The rising factorial is defined as

$x^{\overline{n}}= x (x+1)(x+2) \times ... \times (x+n-1)$ and the falling factorial is defined as

$x^{\underline{n}}= x (x-1)(x-2) \times ... \times (x-n+1)$.

David Branson in his article https://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/34-3/branson.pdf mentiones that

$x^{\underline{-n}} = \frac{1}{(x+1)(x+2) \times ... \times (x+n)}$.

What is $x^{\overline{-n}}$? And where does $(x+1)(x+2) \times ... \times (x+n)$ comes from?

Comment: Can you produce a recurrence connecting $x^{\overline{n}}$ for two consecutive positive values of $n$?  Then use it backward to get a reasonable definition for negative $n$ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let me explain where $x^{\underline{-n}} = \frac{1}{(x+1)(x+2) \times ... \times (x+n)}$ coems from.

First, the falling factorial $\newcommand{\fall}[2]{#1 ^ {\underline{#2}}}\fall xn$ was defined for any nonnegative integer $n$, and any complex $x$. The falling powers can then be seen to obey a certain property, which is analogous to the property $x^{n+m}=x^nx^m$ for ordinary exponentiation.
$$
\fall x{n+m}= \fall xn \cdot \fall {(x-n)}m \tag1
$$
Now, suppose you want to extend the definition of $\fall xn $ to allow for negative arguments of $n$. It would be preferable to choose a definition which preserves the property $(1)$. Applying property $(1)$ with $m=-n$, we get a formula for $\fall x{-n}$ in terms of $\fall xn$.
$$
1=\fall x0=\fall x{n+(-n)}=\fall xn \cdot \fall{(x-n)}{-n}
$$
Substituting $x+n$ for $x$ in the above, we get implies
$$
 \fall{x}{-n}=\frac1{\fall{(x+n)}n}=\frac{1}{(x+1)\cdots(x+n)}
$$
This explains where the formula for $\fall xn$ comes from. It is the unique way to extend the domain of the falling power operation to allow for negative integer exponents, which obeys the sum-to-product rule, $(1)$, that the operation enjoyed when restricted to the natural numbers.

For the rising factorial, you can show that
$$
 x^{\overline{n+m}}= x^{\overline{n}} \cdot {(x+n)}^{\overline m} ,\tag2
$$
and then as before, you can show the unique way to define $x^{\overline{-n}}$ for $n>0$ without violating $(2)$ is
$$
x^{\overline{-n}}=\frac1{{(x-n)}^{\overline{n}}}=\frac{1}{(x-1)\cdots(x-n)}.
$$